# Calculating Max Imbalance of Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am currently coding a recursive method to return the max imbalance on the whole of a Binary Search Tree. I've very new to recursive programming so it's quite difficult to wrap my head around. **The tree I have built has an Imbalance of 1 but my method only returns 0.** I'm sure my logic here is flawed.

I'm 100% sure its running " (root == null){ return 0;} " in every step of the method. I tried removing it and defining it further and it continues to do the same.

This is my current method:

```
public int getMaxImbalance(){
  return Math.abs(getMaxImbalance(root));
}

public int getMaxImbalance (TreeNode<E> root){

  if (root == null){
      return 0;
  }else if(root.left != null && root.right == null){

      return 1 + getMaxImbalance(root.left) + getMaxImbalance(root.right);
              //adds 1 left is true and right is false

  }else if(root.left == null && root.right != null){

      return -1 + getMaxImbalance(root.left) + getMaxImbalance(root.right);
      //adds -1 left is false and right is true

  }

  return getMaxImbalance(root.left) + getMaxImbalance(root.right);
      //calls itself if both fields are null;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your code seems wrong: the max imbalance of a node is not the sum of the max imbalance of its child(ren). Rather, the max imbalance should be the abs of the difference of the height of its child(ren) (if one of them is empty the max imbalance of that node is just 0, so the max imbalance of the current node depends entirely on it's only child).